# $("#txtStartDate").datepicker({}) is not working for me

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

```
  <div class="datePickerContainer">
                            <input class="form-control datepicker bg-color-white" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" maxlength="15" ng-model="PriceLineObj.StartDate" id="txtDate" type="text">
                        </div>
```

and the JQuery code is :

```
  $(function () {

    debugger;

    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        class: "tester",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar-green.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 365,
        beforeShow: function () {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("lbAvalabilityDatePicker")
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('.enddatepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
        }
    });
})
```

Now when I click on the images/calendar-green.gif I am not able to see the calendar. I have already added the required libraries. Please Suggest

Comment: I edited your question to create a runnable snippet but I had to cancel my edits because it was working fine as is. Whatever your problem is it can't be found in the code you've shared. What diagnostics have you made? Does the console show any error? Does the selector match items?

Comment: `I have already added the required libraries` Are you sure? Are they in the right order? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @alvaro : The Order of library was wrong ....corrected it...working now thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

It works when you click on Select Date :

```js
$(function() {
  debugger;
  $("#txtDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    class: "tester",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar-green.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 365,
    beforeShow: function() {
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("lbAvalabilityDatePicker")
    },
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      $('.enddatepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="datePickerContainer">
  <input class="form-control datepicker bg-color-white" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" maxlength="15" ng-model="PriceLineObj.StartDate" id="txtDate" type="text">
</div>
```